# Why is my AES algorithm not producing correct output?

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am designing a copy of the classic AES algorithm. Here is the code. As of now, I just want it to work with 128 so disregard any code for 192/256. I believe the model I am copying is the ECB AES. I know it is not publically used anymore but it is a good place to start. The copy produces output but it does not match that of a trusted AES package (python: Crypto.Cipher). I appreciate all of your help!

Class code

```
class AES:
    def __init__(self, key: str) -> None:
        assert len(key) in [16, 24, 32], "Invalid key length. AES allows 16, 24, or 32 key lengths."
        self.key = key
        self.rounds = {4: 10, 6: 12, 8: 14}[len(key) // 4] 
        self.expanded_key = self.key_schedule(key)

        print(f"Original Key: {self.key} | len={len(self.key)}")
        print(f"Expanded Key: {self.expanded_key}")

    @record_time
    def key_schedule(self, key: str) -> list:
        """Expand the key to be used in encryption."""
        expanded_key = to_matrix(list(key.encode("utf-8")))  # 4x4 matrix

        for index in range(4, 4 * (self.rounds + 1)):
            word_block = expanded_key[index - 1] # 1 byte
            if index % 4 == 0:
                word_block = self.sub_bytes(self.rot_bytes(word_block)) # Rot & Sub
                word_block[0] ^= RCON[index // 4] # RCON
            elif self.rounds > 6 and self.rounds % 4 == 4: # 256
                word_block = self.sub_bytes(word_block)
            word_block = [i ^ j for i, j in zip(word_block, expanded_key[index - 4])] # XOR
            expanded_key.append(word_block)

        return expanded_key # 44 word_blocks => 11 keys

    @record_time
    def encrypt(self, text: str) -> str:
        """Encrypt the given text using the key."""
        plaintext = pkcs7_padding(text.encode("utf-8")) # encodes and adds padding
        word_block_matrix = to_matrix(plaintext)

        self.add_round(word_block_matrix, self.expanded_key[:4])

        for index in range(1, self.rounds):
            word_block_matrix = [self.sub_bytes(wb) for wb in word_block_matrix]
            self.shift_rows(word_block_matrix)
            self.mix_columns(word_block_matrix)
            self.add_round(word_block_matrix, self.expanded_key[4 * index: 4 * (index + 1)])

        # Last round (without mix_columns)
        word_block_matrix = [self.sub_bytes(wb) for wb in word_block_matrix]
        self.shift_rows(word_block_matrix)
        self.add_round(word_block_matrix, self.expanded_key[40:])

        # encrypted_bytes = bytes(encrypted_blocks) # to bytes list
        encrypted_base64 = base64.b64encode(to_bytes(word_block_matrix)) # to base64
        encrypted_text = encrypted_base64.decode('utf-8')

        return encrypted_text
    
    @record_time
    def decrypt(self, text: str) -> str:
        word_block_matrix = to_matrix(text.encode('utf-8')) # encodes to 4x4 matrix
        # print(word_block_matrix)
        # self.add_round(word_block_matrix, self.expanded_key[-4:])

    def rot_bytes(self, word_block: list) -> list:
        """Rotate the bytes in the block to the left by one position."""
        return word_block[1:] + word_block[:1]
    
    def sub_bytes(self, word_block: list, inverse=False) -> list:
        """Apply sub bytes transformation to the block."""
        if inverse:
            return [SBOX_INV[wb] for wb in word_block]
        return [SBOX[wb] for wb in word_block]

    def shift_rows(self, word_block: list, inverse=False) -> None:
        """Shift the rows in the block according to AES specifications."""
        if inverse:
            word_block[1] = [word_block[1][3], word_block[1][0], word_block[1][1], word_block[1][2]] # shifts -1
            word_block[2] = [word_block[2][2], word_block[2][3], word_block[2][0], word_block[2][1]] # shifts -2
            word_block[3] = [word_block[3][1], word_block[3][2], word_block[3][3], word_block[3][0]] # shifts -3
        else:
            word_block[1] = [word_block[1][1], word_block[1][2], word_block[1][3], word_block[1][0]] # shifts 1
            word_block[2] = [word_block[2][2], word_block[2][3], word_block[2][0], word_block[2][1]] # shifts 2
            word_block[3] = [word_block[3][3], word_block[3][0], word_block[3][1], word_block[3][2]] # shifts 3

    def mix_columns(self, word_block_matrix: list, inverse=False) -> None:
        """Apply mix columns transformation to the block."""
        for i in range(4):
            wb0 = word_block_matrix[i][0]
            wb1 = word_block_matrix[i][1]
            wb2 = word_block_matrix[i][2]
            wb3 = word_block_matrix[i][3]

            if inverse: # inverse galois variable b= differs than a non inverse galois
                word_block_matrix[i][0] = galois(wb0, 0xE) ^ galois(wb1, 0xB) ^ galois(wb2, 0xD) ^ galois(wb3, 0x9)
                word_block_matrix[i][1] = galois(wb1, 0xE) ^ galois(wb2, 0xB) ^ galois(wb3, 0xD) ^ galois(wb0, 0x9)
                word_block_matrix[i][2] = galois(wb2, 0xE) ^ galois(wb3, 0xB) ^ galois(wb0, 0xD) ^ galois(wb1, 0x9)
                word_block_matrix[i][3] = galois(wb3, 0xE) ^ galois(wb0, 0xB) ^ galois(wb1, 0xD) ^ galois(wb2, 0x9)
            else:
                word_block_matrix[i][0] = galois(wb0, 2) ^ galois(wb1, 3) ^ wb2 ^ wb3
                word_block_matrix[i][1] = galois(wb1, 2) ^ galois(wb2, 3) ^ wb3 ^ wb0
                word_block_matrix[i][2] = galois(wb2, 2) ^ galois(wb3, 3) ^ wb0 ^ wb1
                word_block_matrix[i][3] = galois(wb3, 2) ^ galois(wb0, 3) ^ wb1 ^ wb2

    def add_round(self, word_block_matrix: list, key: list) -> None:
        """Apply key schedule transformation to the block using the key."""
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                word_block_matrix[i][j] ^= key[i][j]`

utils code
`## UTILS ##
def to_matrix(block: list) -> list:
    """Convert a 16-byte block to a 4x4 matrix."""
    return [list(block[index:index+4]) for index in range(0, len(block), 4)]

def to_bytes(block: list) -> bytes:
    """Convert a 4x4 matrix to a 16-byte block."""
    return bytes(sum(block, []))

def pkcs7_padding(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    """Apply PKCS#7 padding to the data to make it a multiple of 16."""
    padding_length = 16 - len(data) % 16
    padding = bytes([padding_length] * padding_length)
    return data + padding

def pkcs7_padding_undo():
    pass

def galois(a, b):
    p = 0
    for _ in range(8):
        if b & 1:
            p ^= a
        carry = a & 0x80
        a <<= 1
        if carry:
            a ^= 0x1B  # xtime(0x80) in the Galois field (0x1B)
        b >>= 1
    return p % 256

def record_time(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        execution_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"{func.__name__}:\t{execution_time:.6f} seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper
```

I am pretty sure the key scheduling is working. I have narrow down my issue to encrypt.

Comment: Include the example you have tried and the output you are expecting

Comment: Consider using an existing implementation, e.g. https://github.com/boppreh/aes, and using it to generate intermediate values to see where your results start to diverge.

Comment: There are also [official test vectors](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/aes/AESAVS.pdf) although they don't contain intermediate values.